# f(x,y):=x.y is refused "unauthorized change : the variable type is invalid" (but seems working on many examples I see over the Internet...)

Tags: ti-nspire

I erased all the variables of my scratchpad, with `ClearAZ`,
and attempted to enter the multivariable function `f(x,y) := x.y` that I see everywhere over the Internet on my `TI-nspire CX II-T`.

But, myself, I'm receiving the message: "*unauthorized change : the variable type is invalid*"
(I'm translating the message from French, I've received it verbatim like: "*Changement non autorisé : le type de variable est invalide*")

Why? And what should I do?
I have no clues.

Answer (score 0):

**Epilogue:**
I've discovered that I was able to define `g(x,y) := x.y`, but `ClearAZ` or `DelVar` weren't able to really delete my *f* function, that was, in fact, still linked to a graphical representation.

I had to go on the graph tab, then ensure to do the action "*Erase all*" to make the function really disappear from *nspire* memory.

And then defining `f(x,y) := x.y` became possible.